# Open VPN uses the old IP in a dynamic IP server

Tags: openvpn

I have a server that uses dynamic IP. In cludns I have configured a domain to handle that.

I have created MyDomain.Cloudns.net and in the server I have an application that updates the IP.

In my Open VPN client, I have configured it to connect to the MyDomain.Cloudns.net domain, and it works well, but if the server renews its IP, when I start Open VPN, I see that it still tries to connect to the old IP in the log.

I have to wait a lot of time, I am not sure how much, but at least 30 minutes.

It seems that the client saves the IP when it connect successfully to the domain and for the next connections it uses the IP. But if the connection fails, it tries to use that same IP until it fails many times and before it tries to use the domain again.

Is there some way to configure Open VPN to always use the domain, instead of the IP? I guess it is better to use the IP as it is more direct, but is it useful if the server has static IP. Perhaps it would be nice if the client could be configured to use the domain after 3 or 4 attempts to connect, but now I have to wait a long time until Open can connect if the IP changes.

Comment: Probably DNS caching. Clear the DNS cache according to the OS you use before a connection attempt.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using windows 11 in the  client. I have tried to change the IP in the domain, clean the DNS cache in windows and then connect with OpenVPN. It connects because still use the old IP. So I guess it is a internal configuration or cache in OpenVPN.

Comment: Then change the IP again and do a `nslookup`, it doesn't use any cache, so it lets you test if the DNS record is updated yet.

Comment: What TTL do you have configured for the domain name? If the TTL is like 30 minutes, you won't see any changes for 30 minutes... nslookup is still affected by caching – not the OS cache, but it still uses the cache of whatever server it's told to query, so if you're querying e.g. your ISP's DNS server then you'll see the information cached by that server.

Comment: In the control panel of Cloudns I have a TTL of 1 hour for that domain.